# Создание цикла , складывающего два соседних числа из предыдущего элемента матрицы

Tags: python, циклы, list, матрицы, список

Пишу код , который получает следующий ряд чисел, благодаря некоторым преобразованиям

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

ряд «1 4 6 4 1» получается из предыдущего ряда «1 3 3 1» так: в начале всегда 1, 1+3=4, 3+3=6, 3+1=4, в конце всегда 1

Идея такова, что уже есть первые два элемента матрицы и цикл начинается с первого элемента и высчитывает там сумму двух соседних элементов и записывает во второй элемент(нумерацию в матрице начинаю с нуля) ,я пытался как то через это реализовать, но не очень то и получается

```
table = [[1], [1, 1]]
n = int(input())
s = 0
for i in range(n - 2):
  for row in table[i]:
       s += sum(row)
  table.append([s])  
print(table)
```

что исправить в коде, чтобы заработало?

Comment: ```for i in range(n - 2):row = table[-1];table.append([a + b for a, b in zip([0]+row,row+[0])])```

Comment: @Danis при вводе единицы должно вывести просто единицу, а выводит два ряда , на первом единицу, а на втором две единицы

Comment: значит нужно до цикла проверять как то , какое число ввел человек?

Comment: да, сделал проверку, если `n != 1: и наши циклы` и `else: print(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def solve(n: int) -> list:
    retval = [(1,)]  # Начальное состояние
    for _ in range(n - 1):  # Делаем n-1 раз, т.к. первая строка уже задана
        last_row = retval[-1]  # Забираем последнюю строку
        next_row = map(sum, zip(last_row, last_row[1:]))  # Суммируем все пересекающиеся пары из последней строки
        wrapped_next_row = (1, *next_row, 1)  # Добавляем единички с концов
        retval.append(wrapped_next_row)  # Добавляем в итоговое значение очередную строку
    return retval

print(*solve(10), sep='\n')
```

Comment: а что значит этот значок стрелочки между скобкой и `list`? `(n: int) -> list: ` и как можно было бы по другому это записать в более простом виде?

Comment: @марат Это аннотации. Обозначают ожидаемые тип аргумента на входе и результат работы функции. На логику кода они никак не влияют, можно написать и без них. `def solve(n):`.

Answer (score 6):

`pascal_triangle` - бесконечный генератор строк [треугольника Паскаля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F). Следующая строка получается суммированием соседних элементов предыдущей. Для этого к предыдущей строке прибавим нули слева и справа:

```
1 3 3 1 ->    0 1 3 3 1
              1 3 3 1 0
            + ---------
              1 4 6 4 1
```

`itertools.islice` - инструмент для обрезания бесконечных генераторов:

```
import itertools

def pascal_triangle():
    line = (1, )
    while True:
        yield line
        line = tuple(map(sum, zip((0, ) + line, line + (0, ))))

for line in itertools.islice(pascal_triangle(), 5):
    print(*line)
```

> ```
> 1
> 1 1
> 1 2 1
> 1 3 3 1
> 1 4 6 4 1
> ```

Comment: Элегантное решение!

Comment: очень элегантное решение!