# Вопрос по спискам. Python. Как можно упростить мой код?

Tags: python-3.x, list, инспекция-кода

> Треугольник Паскаля — бесконечная таблица биномиальных коэффициентов, имеющая треугольную форму. В этом треугольнике на вершине и по бокам стоят единицы. Каждое число равно сумме двух расположенных над ним чисел.

```
from math import factorial
n = int(input())
my_list = []
for j in range(n):
    c = [int(factorial(j)/(factorial(i)*(factorial(j-i)))) for i in range(j+1)]
    my_list.append(c)

for k in my_list:
    print(*k)
```

Как упростить этот код? Какие ошибки в написании есть, которые лучше не совершать в будущем?

Comment: например считать факториал в цикле , а не вызывая по два раза на каждой итерации

Comment: возможно, стоит вообще сделать массив факториалов и заполнить его один раз, чем вызывать факториал по 3 раза во вложенных циклах. Ну, это если интересует скорость алгоритма вообще.

Comment: Задачу можно решить проще, по определению треугольника Паскаля: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226646/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86/1226659#1226659